# Updating cell in public spreadsheet without need for auth?

Tags: c#, google-api, google-sheets, google-oauth

I have set a spreadsheet to public which I assume would mean a user shouldn't need authorization to access and make changes to it, I should only need to provide my client id and secret? (I'm the only person who will be using this app and the spreadsheet is on my own Google account which is also the owner of the app)

I went through the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/?hl=en

My code works perfectly - it basically just updates a single cell in a spreadsheet with a function and then returns the value of that cell.

The issue is, I don't want to have to keep authorizing through the webpage. Is it possible to skip the need to authorize? Or at least authorize through code automatically instead of manually doing it through a webpage?

```
using Google.GData.Client;
using Google.GData.Spreadsheets;

namespace Spreadsheet{
    class Program{
        static void Main(){
            OAuth2Parameters parameters = new OAuth2Parameters();
            parameters.ClientId = "client-id-here";
            parameters.ClientSecret = "client-secret-here";
            parameters.RedirectUri = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"; //I'm not even sure what this is, I assume it's only necessary for web based applications
            parameters.Scope = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds https://docs.google.com/feeds";

            //This is where the user is required to navigate to a page and retrieve access code
            string authorizationUrl = OAuthUtil.CreateOAuth2AuthorizationUrl(parameters);
            parameters.AccessCode = Console.ReadLine();

            OAuthUtil.GetAccessToken(parameters);
            string accessToken = parameters.AccessToken;

            GOAuth2RequestFactory requestFactory =
      new GOAuth2RequestFactory(null, "Spreadsheet", parameters);
            SpreadsheetsService service = new SpreadsheetsService("Spreadsheet");
            service.RequestFactory = requestFactory;

            //spreadsheet related code here..
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: switch to a service account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is this script running? The code sample you are using tries to get a token every time you run it. You have two options

1. If this code runs on a server and it can store the refresh token securely then, manually get a refresh token and change the script to just get a new access token (using that refresh token) to do the update.
2. Change to using a service account. Service accounts are built to handle these kind of use cases. You get a service account and in the spreadsheet give access to service account (share with it) and using service account you make a request to get an access token that you can use.